# Русское ПЕРШИЙ произошло от FIRST? Или наоборот?

Tags: этимология

Неужели русские ждали когда англичане или шведы подскажут им как называется палец?

По-русски **ПЕРСТ** - "**палец**" произошло из русского же **ПЕРШИЙ**, то есть **ПЕРВЫЙ**.

Поскольку в английском оказывается тоже есть такое слово - **FIRST** - "**первый**", стало быть, русские люди века так до 15-го жили, не имея ни понятия **ПЕРШИЙ** (первый), ни понятия **ПЕРСТ** (палец).

То же слово находим и в шведском языке - **FÖRSTA**, которое переводится "**первый**".

Странно получается, мы знаем, что русские слово с этим корнем **ПЕРШ** употребляли давно, задолго до контактов с англичанами и вообще с Европой, а, оказывается, в это же самое время этими же словами пользовались шведы с англичанами.
Как такое может быть?

Или здесь опять случайное совпадение, как с парами русс.-лат. ЗЕЛО-ZELO и русс.-ит. СТРАННЫЙ-STRANO ?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Господа оппоненты!  есть предложение, смотреть сначала в словари, а потом приводить примеры.
В польском первый - pierwszy, а не perwszy, которое не переводится, оппонент ошибся.
В русском языке есть куча слов с корнем пер(переть, допер, приперло, и тд.  В том числе и сочетание "пер выше"--оттуда и польское. Фамилия ПЕРВЫШЫН. Можно согласиться, что слово первый как раз из польского и пришло, но есть еще славянские языки, в которых явно читается слово первый.
Типичная немецкая запись русских щипящих в латинском алфавите--это замена на сочетание Ш-ST, SHT, SCH, и др. затем возврат. А на то имеются исторические причины. И их много. Так что перст--это возврат.
в польском замена щ-szcz.   barszcz-борщ  в немецком вообще качественное такое -Borschtsch--двойной повтор.
szczupak-щука
szczecina-щетина.
В звучании слов появляется буква Т.
А первый--родственник права и правый. Копипастить из Фасмера конечно можно, но не бесконечно, а в качестве справки для дальнейшего выяснения этимологии.

Answer (score 3):

Нет и нет.
"Перст" и "первый" - не родственники.

> По-русски ПЕРСТ - "палец" произошло из русского же ПЕРШИЙ, то есть ПЕРВЫЙ.

Нет. Перший - от польского pierwszy - первый, с упрощением скопления согласных.

Первый - прямо родственно английскому first - от общего индоевропейского корня, что доказывавется многочисленными потомками во многих индоевропеских.

"Перст" - родственно first, но не английскому, а средневерненемецкому (вершина) и еше куче слов в разных языках со сходными значениями.

Все есть у Фасмера, надоело копипастить каждый раз

- [ПЕРВЫЙ | classes.ru](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-9459.htm)
- [ПЕРСТ | classes.ru](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-9514.htm)

Comment: Нет. Перший - от польского perwszy - первый, с упрочением скопления согласных.

Из чего вытекает, что ПЕРШИЙ - от польского PERWSZY ?

У Фасмера это - не убедительно.

Comment: А у немцев борщ-Borschtsch, упрочнение скопления очень убедительно 
первый по-польски pierwszy.

Comment: >Из чего вытекает, что ПЕРШИЙ - от польского PERWSZY?
  
Из логики. (Я описАлся - pierwszy).  
Мне нравится уже тем, что она непротиворечива.  
Я не исследовал специально это слово. Будет основание отказаться от этой идеи - готов это сделать. Не нравится прямое польское происхождение - рассмотрите версию родственности. В польском cz (Ш) - вроде бы родственно русскому суффиксу сравнительной степени: больше, горше, лучше. Вполне может быть и в "перший".     
(+)==    
Федя, нельзя ж так постоянно вести дискуссию. Вы требуете доказывать все, а вы все отрицаете, ничего не давая взамен.

Comment: Русское БОРЩ не только в английском (BORSCHT).
В турецком, например, есть свой BORS = борщ. 
И у финннов BORSTS-keitto = борщ. 

У бартьев-греков БОРТС тоже = борщ.

Answer (score 2):

Уважаемый Федя, ну как получили консультацию от поклонников Фасмера? Я правильно понял посыл первого "гуру", что "перший" и "первый" слова НЕ родственные, потому что "перший" (кстати, сохранился не только в украинском, но и в белорусском) произошел от польского "пиервжи". А польское "пиервжи", по-видимому, никакого отношения к общеславянскому "[први]" не имеет, а прилетело к ним прямиком из словаря Фасмера, или же из английского, либо из германского. А предки белорусов и украинцев перстов не имели и указывали, по-видимому, другой частью тела. Ну, это же вытекает из всей логики Фасмера в отношении славян и, в частности, самых отсталых из них - русских. Обратите внимание, как настойчиво Вам напоминают: "вы перепутали форум", "вам тут не место", "нечего всяким Федям тут умничать", "пишут бессмыслицы". Даже параноидальные признаки появились у хранителей фасмеровского наследия, они Вас подозревают в раздвоенности или даже растроенности. Любые средства хороши, дабы заткнуть рот иному мнению! :)

Comment: Конечно, Гусляр, я вижу нападающих.
Не хочется с ними пререкаться. Всех не перекричишь.
Когда появятся аргументы, можно будет и беседовать.
А чтобы так просто - я не обращаю внимания на подобные пререкания. Когда нет мысли - как-то не интересно.

К тому же, со стороны виднее. А они - сидят внутри. Оторваться от догмы оттуда не легко.


Я знаю это по историографии. Там точно такая же картина.


Так что, друг мой, терпение и еще раз терпение!